# Print DisplayForm.aspx created by InfoPath

Tags: 2010, infopath, printing, display-form

I need to sometimes print contents of a submitted forms (created in InfoPath) i.e. DisplayForm.aspx in a Printer-Friendly format. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can create a print view of your form with no color in it. Then when you click a "print" button, it will switch to this view and then they can click their print button or press ctrl+p to print.